# How to plot aggregated data in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, aggregation, kibana-4, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm a newbie to kibana. 
I have following data stored in ES:

```
{
"_index": "test",
"_type": "impressions",
"_id": "AVZ4QLgkLqvQLIzbvF4e",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "campaign_id": "1011",
    "count": 691,
    "played_dt": "2016-01-02"
  }
}
```

So, basically I have counts per campaign_id which is already aggregated data.
I want a simple bar chart which plots counts per `campaign_id` where X axis is `campaign_id` and Y axis is it's count.

I'm getting hits for that specific `campaign_id` as unique count rather than the actual value in count field.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Visualize" tab, select "Vertical bar chart":

[image: kibana 4 visualize]

Choose new search and select appropriate index. Now you probably want to visualize your data in time. So, on X axis use "Date histogram" and select your time filed (`played_dt`).

[image: bar chart]

Now you can use e.g. "Split bars", use splitting by terms and select `campaign_id` field.

[image: kibana4 split bars]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Created a stacked bar chart with the above steps.